# Different outputs in browser and mobile - same css

Tags: html, css

ok, first time poster, long time user of the site (when googling for clues).

I'm just starting coding, and made this site (all on plain HTML and CSS - made one in Bootstrap but didn't liked the usability - will test Foundation and Sass+Susy later on).

http://limakeppler.com.br/teste/areas.html

But I got two stupid (I believe) problens.

First: Can't made one css ref to work on mobile and browser window resive (got two entries on the html for the same external css). Ready about proper media-query usage, but can´t make it at all. Some pointers for just having one media-query wich work for both would be nice.

Second: Even with the same css (wich needs some work by the way), in mobile size, I got different results opening the site in Chrome Iphone simulator, or just rescaling the browser window? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my english. If needed, just ask and I will post the relevant code (but for what I saw here, a hosted page would work).

Comment: can you add some code so we can help? and the specific problem you're trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a general question. Different browsers render things differently but usually within a reasonable range. Often major differences in rendering across modern browsers are due to a lack of proper prefix code. If that is the case you can try something like https://autoprefixer.github.io/.

If you're referring to your `<H1>` elements overlapping on mobile device width, it's the padding:1em; that is crushing the text together. Instead you could try using `%` to replace `em`.

Answer (score 0):

found the problem. As I found out, Iphone browser got some weird resizing going on. So I just add

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">`

and everything works as expected. Damn, maybe that's why a framework is not a bad idea :P

thanks for the help anyway.